# cont=getActivity() cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android-fragments, android-asynctask

I want use in **Fragment** a **AsyncTask** and use in AsyncTask **findViewById**.

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category, 
            container, false); 


    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category, container, false);
    cont=getActivity();

    new ProgressTask(cont, myFragmentView).execute();
}




private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;

    public void RecuperarComentarisFoto(Context context, View rootView){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.rootView=rootView;
    }

    LinearLayout barLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.barLayout);
    [...]
```

He say to me that  **cont=getActivity();** *cannot be resolved to a variable*.
What should I setfor **cont**?

Thanks